# Assigning boolean values to integer

Tags: python, boolean

I have a class that represents a bunch of switches that can be either on or off, and I need to able to change the state of whatever switch I choose to from `True` to `False`. How can I set an integer to represent either of those boolean values?

```
class SwitchBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, switches):
        self.switches = switches

    def flip(self, num):
        if num in range(0, self.switches):
            if num == True:
                return "Lightswitch %s is now on!" % num
                num = 1
            else:
                return "Lightswitch %s is now off!" % num
                num = 2
        else:
            return "Lightswitch %s does not exist!" % num
```

Comment: I think what you want is a dictionary.

Comment: Nah, what you need is a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: Think about what `num` is in your code. At one point it seems to be the number of the switch you're trying to flip, but at another point you ask if it is `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
class SwitchBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, num_switches):
        # create a dict of {number: state} key-values
        self.switches = {i: False for i in range(num_switches)}

    def flip(self, num):
        # test for the number being one of the dict's keys
        if num in self.switches:
            if self.switches[num]:
                print("Lightswitch %s was on!" % num)
            else:
                print("Lightswitch %s was off!" % num)
            # flip the value
            self.switches[num] = not self.switches[num]
        else:
            print("Lightswitch %s does not exist!" % num)

    def flip_every_nth(self, n):
        for i in range(0, len(self.switches), n):
            self.flip(i)


x = SwitchBoard(8)
x.switches
x.flip(1)
x.flip(3)
x.flip(1)
x.flip(10)
x.switches
x.flip_every_nth(3)
```

Result:

```
Lightswitch 1 was off!
Lightswitch 3 was off!
Lightswitch 1 was on!
Lightswitch 10 does not exist!
Lightswitch 0 was off!
Lightswitch 3 was on!
Lightswitch 6 was off!
```

Things to note:

- Your `num = 1` and `num = 2` lines will never be executed because they occur after a `return` statement.
- It is not really a good idea to return a string with information like "Lightswitch 3 was on!" - I have changed these to `print`s instead.
- I'm assuming you don't want to have names (only numbers) for your switches, given that you have a function to flip every nth switch.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Why not?

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli No, a single list does not adequately store enough information for OP.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli That comes down to a matter of preference. Do you have a good reason for why I should use a list rather than a dict? If not, please retract your downvote.

Comment: @jmu303 show me, please, because I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @senshin Do _you_ have a _good_ reason to use a dictionary rather than a list, since a list is a simpler data structure that could get the job done?

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli The burden of explanation is on you, because _you_ are the one proposing a change to my solution. In any case, however, yes, I do - using a dictionary here is more Pythonic. Rather than futzing around with ranges or inequalities, we merely test for membership in the dictionary. This more clearly expresses the intent of the code. Furthermore, if OP at some point decides that he wants to name his light switches, a dictionary will be the only reasonable option.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Agreeing with senshin here.

Comment: @senshin ah, yes, finally! So a dictionary is strictly needed only in a different, special, further-improvement case than the one the OP is actually facing. But nowhere in your answer you are offering the simpler alternative, nor you explain why a dictionary as first attempt. To me, that's worth a downvoting, yes. And I heard that Pythonic use of dictionaries is for switch replacements, not list replacements.

Comment: @jmu303 no wonder, since you propose basically the same strategy in your answer.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli You will have to explain to me why using a list is "simpler" than using a dictionary. Both types are Python primitives.

Comment: So even integer numbers are Python primitives: are you willing to tell me that they are of the same complexity of lists or dictionaries?

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli I don't think you understand how argumentation works. You have made the following claim: "lists are simpler than dictionaries". I have asked you to explain your claim. You cannot reply by arguing about a tangentially-related point (no, integers are not as complicated, but they're not collections, so that is neither here nor there). That is not how argumentation works. In any case, it is clear to me that 1.) your understanding of good Pythonic style is severely deficient, and 2.) you are unwilling to discuss this matter like an adult. I am done discussing this.

Comment: I believe I do. You supported your argument that lists and dictionaries are of the same complexity because they both are Python primitive data types. I confuted your argument by means of the integer example: not all primitive data types are of the same complexity. Your turn of explaining why on earth you believe that lists and dictionaries are of the same complexity. But, oh, guess what? They are not. Unless you are a PHP programmer, that is.

Comment: Although I used a list in my answer, I do like the argument that range checking etc is irrelevant to the problem and using a dict is clearer. Senshin's right.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich so please change your answer if you do believe that a dictionary-based alternative is clearer.

Comment: I added a note, but now I must sleep.

Comment: This is my favourite answer, even though I may have to go with a list because I have another method that will flip the state of every nth switch. So I would need a list for that right? Since dicts are ordered?

Comment: @Amon You're right, dictionaries are not ordered. However, there is a straightforward way to achieve a "flip every nth switch" method while still using a dictionary - I will edit it into my answer in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to track a number of switches. You could store a list of True, False values and update them:

```
class SwitchBoard(object):
    def __init__(self, num_switches):  # Clearer name
        self.num_switches = num_switches
        self.states = [False] * num_switches  # All off

    def flip(self, num):
        if 0 <= num < self.num_switches:  # Why create a whole range?
            # Do flip:
            self.states[num] = not self.states[num]

            return "Lightswitch %d is now %s!" % (
                num, "on" if self.states[num] else "off")
        else:
            return "Lightswitch %d does not exist!" % num
```

Edit: senshin's answer is very similar except it uses a dictionary. That's probably a better choice than a list, because that way it works regardless of the names chosen for the switches, while a list only works if they happen to be consecutive integers starting from 0. The fact that his solution can simply use 'in' as a check seems to confirm that feeling.

Comment: Your use of `self.num_switches` is redundant. The check on the first line of `flip` could just use `len` for the second comparison.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, for this problem a list or dict would work. Since the switches will ever only be in consecutive order(my fault for not clarifying that originally) I technically don't need more than a list, even though a dict is more useful and I found it easier to understand.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli: I know, but in the original code that number was saved. I don't know what he's solving exactly and what the rest of his code needs, but I try not to change too much about an OP's code at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple options:

One, using a dictionary. So, `self.switches` would look something like this:

```
self.switches = {
    1: True,
    2: False,
    3: True,
    4: True
}
```

To access the values in your `flip` function, you'd do something like this. Take note that in python, you don't need to say `if value == True`;, rather, just use the boolean value itself: `if value`:

```
def flip(self, num):
    try:
        if self.switches[num]: # On
            print("Turning switch off!")
            self.switches[num] = False
        else: # Off
            print("Turning switch on!")
            self.switches[num] = True
    except KeyError: # No switch in dictionary!
        print("Switch does not exist!")
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to add more properties to the switches, you could create a class:

```
class Switch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.on = True # default to on
```

`self.switches` would be a list of `Switch` objects:

```
def flip(self, num):
    if num > len(self.switches):
        print("Switch does not exist!")
        return
    if self.switches[num].on: # On
        print("Turning switch off!")
        self.switches[num].on = False
    else:
        print("Turning switch on!")
        self.switches[num].on = True
```

Edit: In response to Giulio's comments about using a list of boolean values:

Yes, such a data structure would be simpler for this use. However, given, OP, you are making a class, I'm assuming that there will be more to your switchboard than flipping switches on and off - otherwise, your usage of a class isn't really necessary in the first place. A list of boolean values is a very fragile way of representing the data you want. As soon as you require additional functionality, you'll have to rewrite your code; for example, if you want to name the switches anything other than consecutive integers, or give them colors, or perhaps remove them from the board entirely.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Sorry, what? A list does not adequately store enough information for OP. You could use two lists, or you could use a dictionary. There's nothing wrong with my answer. If you downvoted, please tell me how I can improve.

Comment: Please explain why a dictionary is needed. I fail to see why a simple list of boolean values cannot be enough. Then I'll reconsider my vote.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Okay, you're correct - a simple list of boolean values is sufficient. However, that's about all a list is capable of representing. A dictionary or class allows for more expansion.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli and at the very least, usage of a dictionary is simpler than the currently most-upvoted answer suggesting two concurrent lists.

Comment: Yeah, I am correct. Then, you are wrong also w.r.t. the currently most-upvoted answer, which uses just one list, and saves the number of switches (an integer, presumably) in a instance variable. You earned your downvote.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli I misread, but that answer's usage of both an instance variable representing the number of switches and a list of that length is redundant. Anyways, again, dictionaries or classes are far more expansible should OP want to build on his switchboard. As soon as OP needs anything besides a flip function, a list representation fails.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed redudant. And yes, dictionaries and classes are extensible in usage and development farther than lists. But you don't even mention lists in your answer, and you don't explain why the dictionary is needed. Why don't stick to the OP actual needs, then (and only then) possibly extending with more proposals?

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli In any matter, Giulio, there's no need to be so caustic and aggressive, towards me and towards senshin. You may express your belief that there is a simpler alternative without sarcastic questions like "Really?" and "Come on!".

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli If we were going to stick to OP's actual needs. I'd argue that he shouldn't even be making a class, rather, a variable containing a list of boolean values. Given that OP is building a class, however, I'm assuming there will be more than just a list and a flip function. Why not create a data structure that will expand with OP's needs?

Comment: Yeah, you should argue that! I'm serious! You should even argue that it's not a good programming practice to return such UI messages from a function of a class that seems to model a business logic object! You should, because errors in the OP script seems so basic that it seems he is just learning Python and/or programming, thus any basic advice could help. As any basic solution, or any solution that _starts_ from basic stuff and only _then_ possibly expands on it.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Why are you so aggressive? Please, let's keep this discussion civil.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli The bare necessities (i.e. a list of boolean values) are nice, but for a beginner, it's good to use a data structure that will give him room to expand so that OP won't be returning in two days to ask why his list structure is inadequate. It's like buying a house with nothing but the bare necessities, which, although efficient, is not at all practical.

Comment: It's not a matter of efficiency. It's a matter of learning. Learning starts from the bare necessities.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Although a list is in Python less *complex* than a dictionary, it is not necessarily *easier to understand*, nor is it more *practical* - not by a long shot, and I doubt the beginning programmer cares about any speed advantages.

Comment: See my previous comment: it's not a matter of speed or efficiency. And I'd maintain that a list is indeed simpler and easier to understand. For the case at hand, with the implicit requirements in the OP code, I'd also maintain that it's more practical.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli Well, this is where our beliefs conflict, and I really don't want to continue this discussion, so I'm going to move on.

Comment: @jmu303 I was using a class because I wanted to store the state of the  switch, on or off. So I a list would meet that criteria, but I found the dict to be easier to read/grasp